# RubyMotion REPL : selecting wrong objects when inspecting

Tags: ios, debugging, read-eval-print-loop, rubymotion

I'm having a problem specifically when using UICollectionViewController's that presents a grid view with UIImageView's with UIImage's, when I try clicking on these object in the REPL, it selects the wrong elements, or it seems as if the representation of the object are not synced with where the actual reference are placed(?). I have no idea.

**Here's what it looks like in the REPL for me:**
The small circle is where my mouse is hovering while pressing cmd. The big circle is the object that is being selected.

[image]

Any ideas?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It may be because of your zoom level or orientation. I occasionally get warnings about zoom level when holding down CMD - try giving different settings a try.

Comment: @Dan2552

Sorry, which zoom are you talking about? I have a 100% scale on the simulator (cmd + 1) and I haven't done any manual zooming as far as I know.

Comment: yeah I meant the scale, try 75 and 50 and see if they help. Obviously I'm not sure. I also wonder if Retina MacBooks cause an issue with it. I've never really had any luck with it so I never use it.

Comment: I see. Anyway, scaling was not the solution.

Comment: Did you this issue go away for you? Could you give us some source code?